# pandas df not recognizing length of column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have this df:

```
columns = ['Item', 'Quant', 'Cost', 'Tot_Cost']

- 0   Item              5382 non-null   object 
- 1   Quantity          4756 non-null   object 
- 2   Unit_Measurement  4757 non-null   object 
- 3   Unit_cost         4753 non-null   object
- 4   Total_cost        5065 non-null   object
```

Poor attempt at copying `df.info()` from Jupyter above

I want to search through `df["Item"]` and if it contains r'(?i)Product create a new column with string in `df["Item"]`.

When I run some code to check if it will somewhat work:

```
bill_df['Product'] = [bill_df['Item'].str.contains(r'(?i)Product',na=False)]
```

Also tried `bill_df.loc[:,"Item"]` just in case

I get this: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (5383)

I noticed this when I originally tried a for loop, I set it to put "False" in new column, but it won't populate 5 values.

Has anyone see this before?

Comment: It is not clear what your desired output is. Does this command do the job? `bill_df['Product'] = np.where(bill_df['Item'].str.contains(r'(?i)Product', na=False), bill_df['Item'], '')`

Comment: I want to loop through column "Item" if string contains 'Product', copy that string and add it in new column 'Product'. 
Product column would look like this: 
'Blank' or NaN (not sure) \n
'Blank' or NaN \n
Product: Pizza \n
'Blank' or NaN

Comment: My command above should do what you are looking for.. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ric, you are a legend. I am grinding since I have moved to Python from Excel and wouldn't still be grinding if not for people like you who take the time to help out.

Comment: I would not say I'm a legend, but thank you for the compliment :)   I'm going to post my comment as an answer so that you can upvote and accept it, and it will be helpful for future users

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of conditional statement that can be easily addressed with the numpy function [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np

bill_df['Product'] = np.where(bill_df['Item'].str.contains(r'(?i)Product', na=False), bill_df['Item'], '')
```